# Prompt User to enable bluetooth in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Are there any workaround which I can use to prompt a user to enable bluetooth in Xamarin Forms / C#?

Like a Display Alert with 'Yes' or 'No' for prompting the user to switch on the bluetooth in case its not enabled.

If the user selects, 'Yes', the bluetooth is enabled.

Please help me to achieve this in both Android and iOS ! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### iOS

On iOS you can not change bluetooth programmatically without using private API's (which Apple does not allow in the App Store), the most you can do is redirect the user to the Bluetooth Settings with this code (note that it only works on a real device):

```
// Is bluetooth enabled?
var bluetoothManager = new CoreBluetooth.CBCentralManager();
if (bluetoothManager.State == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff) {
    // Does not go directly to bluetooth on every OS version though, but opens the Settings on most
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth")); 
}
```

**Be aware that this method will prevent your app from getting App Store approval, since 'App-Prefs:root' is also considered a private API with this explanation:** (thanks to @chucky for mentioning that)

> Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

So for iOS there is no possibility without risk for app rejection.

### Android

```
Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
// is bluetooth enabled?
bluetoothAdapter.IsEnabled;

bluetoothAdapter.Disable();
// or
bluetoothAdapter.Enable();
```

The `BLUETOOTH` and `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission are required for this method to work.

Comment: But can I enable a check if the bluetooth is not on in iOS ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. I suggest you test this thoroughly, as I'm not very sure on top of my head if the iOS `State` property is always 100% correct in every situation.

Comment: Ok. thanks bro ! I'll test this out and revert back to you shortly.

Comment: bluetoothManager.State returns me null. 

Why can't it check if the bluetooth is powered on in iOS ?

Comment: `null` or `Unknown`? It shouldn't be `null`.

Comment: It is unknown.. But not it is fixed. It returns me off when its off.

However, I've used a DisplayAlert which should be prompted to turn on the bluetooth if ever it is off.. The Display Alert does show for some reasons in iOS. Any workaround ?

Comment: Could you help please ?

Comment: I don't have enough to go by with the current information, can you somehow show a project that displays the behaviour (through Github for example)?

Comment: Here is my code.. https://pastebin.com/x3QuhRZY

The _manager returns me `Unknown`. It does not get the information if the bluetooth is Powered On or Off. Any idea on this ?

Comment: That's not enough context. There must be something else that causes the behaviour. For example, where and when you call it could matter.

Comment: Can't test it right now, but try if [`CBPeripheralManager`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/CoreBluetooth.CBPeripheralManager/) gives you better results.

Comment: I have even tried with CBPeripheralManager, but yields no result :( It still returns me unknown

Comment: Downvoted because you will get rejected from the app store using this approach. If you use `root=Bluetooth`, you will get the message "Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change." from Apple. You can only access the general settings using `UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("app-settings:");`.

Comment: I've updated the answer accordingly. You can always edit the answer to make sure it is more correct instead of downvoting and adding a comment (which people often don't read). Thanks for the clarification though!

Answer (score 2):

I dont know about iOS,

If you are looking for navigating to Bluetooth settings in Android from your app in the click of a button. Here is the code:

```
    private void OpenBluetoothSettings()
    {
        Intent intentOpenBluetoothSettings = new Intent();
        intentOpenBluetoothSettings.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionBluetoothSettings);
        intentOpenBluetoothSettings.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intentOpenBluetoothSettings);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Forms

```
if(await DisplayAlert(null,"Enable Bluetooth","Yes", "No"))
{
    // Enablebluetooth here via custom service
}
```

For bluetooth implementation download [Xamarin.BluetoothLE](https://github.com/tbrushwyler/Xamarin.BluetoothLE/) in nugget or you can implement your own

In PCL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test.App
{
    public interface IBluetoothService
    {
        void OpenBluetooth();
        
    }
}
```

In Android

```
using System;
using BluetoothLE.Core;
using Android.Bluetooth;
using Java.Util;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using BluetoothLE.Core.Events;

namespace Test.App.Droid.Services
{
    public class BluetoothService : IBluetoothService
    {
    
        public void OpenBluetooth()
        {
        //native code here to open bluetooth
        }
    
    }
    
}

// register it on MainActivity


// do the same in ios
```

Comment: I need the custom service for ios and android.

Comment: `
private CBCentralManager mgr;
if (mgr.State == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff)
            {
// what should be added here?
            }`